# Is there something similar to OPENJSON in android?

Tags: android, kotlin

> OPENJSON is a table-valued function that parses JSON text and returns objects and properties from the JSON input as rows and columns.
> [OPENJSON](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/openjson-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15)

I want to deserilize Json into objects, but I want to access parts of the Json not parse it all.
I'm using android Kotlin with Room database, if there is a solution in Room maybe.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use any pure java library in android.   Google GSON would be a good choice and with some minimal tweaking you can ignore unnecessary parts of JSON objects